# How to make glyphicon-eye open or close in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

In my form for each field am using glyphicon-eye and if the user clicks on that eye open icon then it should change to eye close.

I need to call a function during ng-click and if eye is close then i need to pass that field name as key inside array.

```
<input  type="text" name="fname" class="form-control1" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="model.firstName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" ng-minlength =1 placeholder="First Name"/>
    <a id="menu-toggle" ng-click="hiddenFileds()" ng-model="model.fnamei" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>

<input  type="text" name="lname" class="form-control1" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="model.lastName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" ng-minlength =1 placeholder="Last Name"/>
     <a id="menu-toggle" ng-click="hide()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
```

Comment: You should take a look at ng-class

Comment: can u please create fiddle link

Comment: have a scope variable eyeOpen and on ng-click="eyeOpen=!eyeOpen", then use class="glyphicon" ng-class="{true:'glyphicon-open', false:'glyphicon-close'}[eyeOpen]".  You have to create a fiddle, so someone can start from there.  It takes less than 2 minutes to create one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kbjwymbq/15/       but in this fiddle my glyphicon is not visible. I don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<input  type="text" name="fname" class="form-control1" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="model.firstName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" ng-minlength =1 placeholder="First Name"/>

<a id="menu-toggle" ng-click="hideName = (hideName?false:true)" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-eye-open':!hideName, 'glyphicon-eye-close':hideName}"></i></a>
```

Comment: change in one icon affects all other

Comment: u need to use separate variable variables, for handle

Comment: How to set value = true if glyphicon-eye is closed

Comment: @kalai look the ng-click operation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jihin Raju. Its working but I faced some css issue. So I used below code and now it is working fine.

```
$scope.user = {
        fname: "firstname",  
        lname: "lastname"
    };

    $scope.allow = {};

    $scope.users = [];

    $scope.push = function(){
        $scope.users = [];
        var user = {}, 
            allow = $scope.allow;
      Object.keys(allow).forEach(function(key){
        allow[key] ? user[key] = $scope.user[key] : null;
      });
      $scope.users.push(user);
    }
```

Instead of href I used input type="checkbox" and label

```
<label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allow.fname, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allow.fname}" ng-click="push(allow.fname = allow.fname?false:true)"><input class="eyecheck" type="checkbox" ng-model="allow.fname" ng-hide="allow.fname || !allow.fname"/></label>
```